# WordPress does not import all pages and post

Tags: import, export

I moved my site from WordPress.com to WordPress.org using its own tools (export/import/.xml file) I followed the import feature provided, but at the end WordPress.org does not imported all the pages, post and pictures. What did I wrong? maybe you have any clue, it is maybe because I changed themes and plugins?

Thank you in advance